# Buuble sort to find five most smallest element in an array

Tags: bubble-sort

I have an array list with some integer values, and I need to find only the five smallest element from the list. Is it efficient to use bubble sort than using any other sorting algorithm? or what is the best algorithm for this?

Comment: Bubble sort is not efficient....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common approach is to use a binary heap to track the *n* smallest elements while scanning from one end to the other.

However, for five elements, it might be just as efficient to track the five smallest seen so far in a simple array. For each new element you inspect, if it's smaller than all the elements in the array, replace the largest with the new element.

Comment: "five smallest seen so far in a simple array" does this means selection sort

Comment: @MuhammadRamshad - no - it means a sort is not required, just scan through your arraylist once and only store the smallest 5 integer values you find, in a separate arry.